# How to format code blocks in Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus

I want to post some code to Google Plus. Eg.:

```
#!/bin/sh
adb shell screencap p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > adb-screenshot$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).png
```

but dashes `-` makes the code stroke through. How can I make it look like here on Stack Exchange, Slack or Github?

I want to make it look something like this:

[image: code highlighting on Slack]

Comment: One solution I thought of right now is to use gist.github.com

Comment: Related: [Write code with indentation in Google+'s stream](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17358)

Comment: Or where do I register feature request?

Answer (score 3):

Google+ Does not support code formatting in posts.

Comment: It's so sad :( :/